# Solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x - t + 2}{2x + t + 1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble with the following question:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x - t + 2}{2x + t + 1}$$

If the independent terms (meaning $+2$ and $+1$) weren't there, this ode would be a routine application of the solution method for homogeneous ode. Nonetheless they are there, and that makes it untackleable for me, because the methods I know are not applicable.

So I'd be very grateful if some of you show me the light. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can transform this equation into a homogeneous one by substituting $t=u+h$ and $x=v+k$ for appropriate values of $h$ and $k$. If we do this, the right-hand side becomes
$$\frac{v+k-u-h+2}{2k+2v+u+h+1},$$
so we want $k-h+2=0$ and $2k+h+1=0$ so that the "independent terms" vanish. Solving these equations simultaneously for $h$ and $k$, we get $h=1=-k$. Thus, we have$^1$
$$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{v-u}{u+2v},$$
which can be solved homogeneously to get a function $v=v(u)$.

Then to switch back to $x$ and $t$, just substitute back $u=t-1$ and $v=x+1$ into the resulting equation.

---

$^1$ This is the case since our change of variables are simply translations, so $dx=dv$ and $dt=du$.

Comment: wao, you not only anwered my question but provide a tool to be able to recognize the change of variable that are necessary to make in theese cases. Thank you so much, men, Thank you so much.

Comment: @Aldebaran No problem :) If you're happy with my answer, please click the green tick next to it to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $$t=z+1,x=v-1$$ then we get
$$\frac{dv(z)}{dz}=\frac{-z+v(z)}{z+2(v(z)-1)+2}$$
Now we substitute
$$v(z)=zu(z)$$ then we get
$$\frac{\frac{du(z)}{dz}{2(u(z)+1)}}{-2u(z)^2-1}=\frac{1}{z}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Nicely done. Thanks you so much. Now it is an homogeneous ode I of course I can terminate it. But another question fall by its own weight: how do you know which change of variables to make??